# How to get $extraVars after creating an order in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

i'm creating order manually with extravars like this

```
$extra_vars = Array();
$extra_vars['slip_id'] = $result['data']['slip_id'];
$extra_vars['language'] = $result['data']['language'];
$extra_vars['expires_at'] = $expires_at;
$extra_vars['barcode'] = $result['data']['barcode'];

$this->module->validateOrder($this->context->cart->id, $status, $total, $checkout_label, NULL, $extra_vars, NULL, false, $customer->secure_key, NULL);
```

The order is creating successfully, but i cannot retrieve the saved extravars data, i have checked ps_order and ps_order_details table but i could not find extravars, can someone please help me to get the extravars, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$extra_vars` is not saved to database but only used so that custom data can be displayed in order confirmation emails.

If you want extra data in order you will need to override the `Order` class to define extra fields and add these fields in the `orders` table.

Comment: i'm new to prestashop, can you please giveme an example on how to do that, thanks